# Optimize summarize of a column until himself

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want have column of summarize til current row like this:

```
id     mount     total

1       1000      1000
2       2500      3500
3       5000      8500
```

As you see total calculate mount summarize til himself. The best query I found is:

```
SELECT
  *,
  (SELECT SUM(mount) from `table` WHERE id <= t.Id) AS total
FROM `table` AS t
```

but, on 200,000 records, it takes about 7 seconds!! 
can suggest me any other way to optimize the query?

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: why to use subquery rather then go for select t.id,t.amount,SUM(tt.amount) from @t t
inner join @t tt
on t.id >= tt.id
group by t.id,t.amount

Comment: [I believe this link will answer your question best.](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals)

Comment: Are you sure you're using SQL Server? The syntax looks a lot like MySQL.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008+, you can use the cumulative sum function:

```
SELECT t.*, SUM(mount) OVER (ORDER BY ID)
FROM `table` t;
```

Otherwise, there are various ways to express the logic in SQL, all equally inefficient:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (SELECT SUM(t.mount) from `table` t2 WHERE t2.id <= t.Id) AS total
FROM `table` t;
```

(I would encourage you to *always* use table aliases, particularly with correlated subqueries.)

This is a rare case where using a cursor might be more efficient than a set-based approach.

Comment: Actually, this will also work on sql server 2008. [see fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5da9ef/3)